# javascript to overrule specifically declared css style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Through a database process I end up with html that contains "spans" that are colored. For example:

```
<div id="RelevantDiv">the industry's standard <span style="background-color: red">dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley</span> of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five.</div>
```

Generally I want to retain this coloring.  However, I also want to build a javascript function that toggles this background color on or off.  I have tried the following:

```
function HLtoggle()
{
var element = document.getElementById('RelevantDiv');
element.style.background = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

However, this doesn't work because the span's are obviously overwriding the

Comment: did u try using the !important rule? element.style.background = '#FFFFFF !important'; also do you call anywhere your function?

Comment: Your background-color is on the `span` element and in the js your are getting the whole `div`. Also, you mix the `background-color` property with the shorthand property `background`

Comment: Use [jquery](http://jquery.com). It's easier.

Comment: Tried using the important designation and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: check my answer with provided fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Your `background-color` is on the span element while in the js your are targetting the parent `div`.

Try the following :

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('#RelevantDiv > span')[0];
element.style['background-color'] = '#FFFFFF';
```

Although, I suggest you to give a class name to your highlighted span, and select by that class and not by the tag name.

Answer (score 0):

In general to change the color on a span you can use

```
var element = document.getElementById('RelevantDiv');
element.style.background = '#FFFFFF';
```

I assume,you want to target the span and not the whole div thus, put the id on span like this

```
<span id="RelevantDiv" style="background-color: red">
```

Now to wrap it up in a function you wrote it correctly in the code provided but you need to call that function usually by using an event handler if you want to call it at certain times.

Here is a jsfiddle for calling the function when you mouse over the span.

https://jsfiddle.net/oLfyx0h5/4/

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing at the div, not the span so the css isn't overridden.  Try this:

```
<div id="RelevantDiv">the industry's standard <span id='span_id' style="background-color: red">...
```

Then change the function

```
 function HLtoggle()
{
    var element = document.getElementById('span_id');
    element.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
}
HLtoggle()
```

Comment: Is there a way to just apply a style to all spans?

Comment: var element = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]; will get you the first span found - getElementsByTagName returns a collection.

Comment: If you want to get all of the spans, then do this:                                        var element = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
        for (var i = 0; i< element.length; i++) {
            element[i].style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
        }

Comment: Thank you so  much. That worked perfectly. Any quick advice on how to make it possible to toggle between being set to FFFFFF and returning to its original value?